# How could I delete 50% of the smileys from a text, selected randomly, with Ruby?

Tags: regex, ruby, match, gsub, indices

For example:

```
"Hi! How :) are :) you? I'm :) fine.:)".magic()
=> "Hi! How are :) you? I'm fine.:)"
or
=> "Hi! How are :) you? I'm :) fine."
or
...
```

Only :) smiley should be supported for deletion or replacing.

Comment: There seems to be some subtle whitespace removal in your example, e.g. `How␣:)␣are` becomes `How␣are` instead of `How␣␣are`. Is this actually expected and if so, what are the rules?

Comment: In text double spaces are usually not allowed, or sub-optimal, so somehow they must be garbage-collected.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

- [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) to get all occurences of the smiley
- [Array#sample](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) to make a random selection of which to remove
- [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a block parameter to iterate through matches and select positions to substitute with empty string

Code:

```
class String
  def magic()
    len = scan(/:\)/).length
    pos_to_remove = (0 ... len).to_a.sample(len / 2)
    gsub(/:\)/).with_index { |_, i|
      if pos_to_remove.include?(i) then "" else ":)" end
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: You can use `gsub(/:\)/).with_index { |_, i| ... }` instead of the manual counter.

Comment: @Stefan - thanks, this simplifies it, I updated my answer.

Comment: Another possible method, based on split:

`"Hi! How :) are :) you? I'm :) fine.:)".split(/(:\) *)/).collect.with_index.map{|z,i| [z,i]}.group_by{|z| /^:\) *$/.match?(z[0])}.map{|k,v| k ? v.shuffle.yield_self{|w| w.first(w.size/2)} : v}.flatten(1).sort_by{|z| z[1]}.transpose[0].join`

Answer (score 1):

The key is to match two `:)` at the same time but only capture one of them in the group.

- regex

```
(:\).*?):\)\s*
```

or

```
:\)\s*(.*?:\))
```

- substitution

```
\1
```

See the test case [here](https://regex101.com/r/XdlyCA/1)

```rb
"Hi! How :) are :) you? I'm :) fine.:)".gsub(/(:\).*?):\)\s*/, '\1')
# => Hi! How :) are you? I'm :) fine.
```

Comment: This will always remove the same smileys, what about the randomness?

Comment: @Stefan My bad, I didn't see it must be random. Then it cannot be done by only regex. Try Kombajn's answer.